# git - remote: fatal: you are on a branch yet to be born, using post-receive hook

Tags: git, github, githooks

So I am trying to sync to github branches to two parts of my website, theoretically the master branch in my [github](https://github.com/wesleynw/tinyweatherstation.com) should be synced with my website [tinyweatherstation.com](http://tinyweatherstation.com) and the beta branch should sync with [beta.tinyweatherstation.com](http://beta.tinyweatherstation.com), and I have successfully gotten the post-receive hook working with the master branch, but when this for the beta branch:

```
git remote add live_beta ssh://wesley@tinyweatherstation.com/var/www/tinyweatherstation.com.git
git push live_beta +beta:refs/heads/beta
```

I get the error:

```
    Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/WesleyN/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 999, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (967/967), done.
Writing objects: 100% (999/999), 5.04 MiB | 529.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 999 (delta 360), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (360/360), done.
remote: fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
To ssh://tinyweatherstation.com/var/www/beta.tinyweatherstation.com.git
 * [new branch]      beta -> beta
```

The post receive hook looks like this...

`#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/beta.tinyweatherstation.com/html git checkout -f`

I have commited to this branch (beta) so I know it is there, so please help...

Comment: The error is coming from the post-receive hook. Until you show us the actual post-receive hook, though, we can only guess what's going on.

Comment: I edited the post with the receive hook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message comes from the target of the push (the Git there).  Given that your post-receive hook is the simple one line expression:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/beta.tinyweatherstation.com/html git checkout -f
```

this means that the Git living at:

```
ssh://tinyweatherstation.com/var/www/beta.tinyweatherstation.com.git
```

is, just as the error message says, "on a branch yet to be born".  That is, the *current* branch of that (presumably bare) repository has some name, such as `master`, but that branch name does not yet exist.

There are multiple solutions.  One is to pick an explicit branch to check out:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/beta.tinyweatherstation.com/html git checkout -f beta
```

That way, this particular Git knows to check out by the name `beta` rather than its current branch (again, probably `master`—from here on, I'll assume that it *is* `master`) that does not actually exist yet.

Another is to *create* the branch name `master` in that Git repository (on the server at `tinyweatherstation.com/var/www/beta.tinyweatherstation.com.git`).  There are multiple ways to do this: e.g., you could log in on that machine, navigate to the bare repository, and use `git branch` to make the name `master` point to any of the existing commits, now that there are some commits in the repository.  Or, from your client machine, you could do another `git push`, but this time, do one that pushes to the name `master`:

```
client$ git push live_beta master
```

(assuming you want the server's `master` to point to the same commit that your client's `master` points-to).

Yet another way is to log in to the server and change the name to which its `HEAD` points symbolically, i.e., to change the *name* of the current branch on the `tinyweatherstation.com` server:

```
server$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/beta
```

Now the `git checkout -f` with no branch name will work, because the name `beta` refers to the branch you pushed earlier.

Note that using `git checkout -f beta` will, as a side effect, *set* the current branch *to* `beta`.

Answer (score 0):

- Fetch all repository:

  ```
  $ git remote add live_beta ssh://wesley@tinyweatherstation.com/var/www/tinyweatherstation.com.git
  $ git fetch --all
  ```
- Create and checkout to `beta` branch with remote's `beta` branch history ( make sure no local `beta` branch exists):

  ```
  $ git checkout beta
  ```
- Push to `live_beta` repo's `beta` branch:

  ```
  $ git push live_beta beta
  ```