# I've updated Git and 'lost my Head', so now I can't commit

Tags: git, git-commit, drive

I recently downloaded git 2.19.0.windows.1. In the previous versions of git, I could git clone and git commit from/to both my local drive and my H drive. Now with this version of git, I can only git clone and commit on my local drive but not on my H drive. When I commit on my H drive I get the following error:

```
 fatal: cannot update the ref 'HEAD': unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Bad file descriptor
```

I have tried to find my head using the following code:

```
 $ echo ref: refs/head/master >.git/HEAD
```

This does not work, I don't know what the next move is.

Comment: Could there be some more general permissions/access issue at work here?  Have you had any similar problems with your `H:` drive besides this problem with Git?

Comment: Did you try to just checkout a branch? It should reset HEAD.

Comment: No problems similar to this. Not sure why it would work with the previous version but not this version.

Comment: When I checkout from the branch I get the following error `fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born`

Comment: @RomainVALERI the git reset made no difference

Comment: `.git/logs/HEAD` is for reflog. Seems it's corrupted. Make a backup and remove it and see if it will be okay.

Comment: @sos.cott err... just clarifying... `git reset` has nothing to do with the `git checkout` I hinted at. I'll just guess you were in fact colloquially refering to checkout. I'm the one who introduced confusion in the first place with my "It should reset HEAD". I meant "It should set your HEAD correctly" ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first what `git status` and `git config -l` when done in your repository on `H:\`: when in doubt (in an IDE), fall back to the command line.

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24001609/6309), a branch yet to be born generally means an new empty repo where at least one commit is needed.

That or, as [illustrated there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51176731/6309):

- you have an environment variable `GIT_WORK_TREE` or `GIT_DIR` set referencing another repo
- your .git/refs/HEAD does not reference an existing branch (you can open it and see its content)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue recently. I am not sure of the root cause at this time, but I deleted the `.git/logs/HEAD` folder and then the commit went through just fine.