# Git post-receive hook fails to checkout, fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born

Tags: git, remote-server, githooks

On my server, in `/home/user/git/domain.com.git/`, I ran `git init --bare`, then created `post-receive` file in `hooks` dir & `chmod +x hooks/post-receive`. I used `ls -la` to verify it is executable.

My `post-receive` file:

```
mkdir /home/USER/pub/domain.com
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/USER/pub/domain.com git checkout -f
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/USER/pub/domain.com git reset --hard
```

I execute `git push remotename branchname` from local and get the error:

```
remote: fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

It also shows:

```
To ssh://domain.com/~/git/domain.com.git
   oldcommithash..newhash  branchname -> branchname
```

I know the post-receive hook is running because my `mkdir` gives me a directory already exists error, which is to be expected and causes no problems on my other sites using this setup.

I also have this problem with `git push remotename HEAD` which is what I want to use, ultimately, for simpler scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My latest `hooks/post-receive` script, which will update `/home/user/PATH` with the most recent push.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

user=REMOTE_USER_NAME
path=pub/domain.com

# Loop over all pushed branches
c=0;
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    # track count of branches
    c=$((c + 1))
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref "$refname")
done
# If more than one branch was pushed, give an error & return
if [[ $c -gt 1 ]];then
    echo ""
    echo "Multiple branches were pushed. Cannot update remote site."
    echo ""
    return;
fi
# Make the directory. Gives an error if it exists, but who cares?
mkdir "/home/${user}/${path}"

# Checkout the pushed branch & reset --hard
GIT_WORK_TREE="/home/${user}/${path}" git checkout -f "${branch}"
GIT_WORK_TREE="/home/${user}/${path}" git reset --hard
```

### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13057643/802469 gave me the while loop for this solution
- a near duplicate [git - remote: fatal: you are on a branch yet to be born, using post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166403/git-remote-fatal-you-are-on-a-branch-yet-to-be-born-using-post-receive-hook) which suggests specifying the name of the branch, but it's not quite what I wanted